# Question regarding probability in maths

Tags: probability

The question is as follows -: there are 5 cards in a box each labelled from 1 to 5 if two cards are picked from box simultaneously then what are the possible outcomes for the 2 cards and what is the probability to get both even numbered cards?

Comment: Did you try it.

Comment: Yea the outcomes are 1,2 1,3 1,4 1,5 2,3 2,4 2,5 3,4 3,5 4,5 and p(e) is 1÷10 Or so I think I don't know if it's right

Comment: That's correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possible outcomes are: 
$(1,2), (1,3), (1,4), (1,5), (2,3), \color{blue}{(2,4)}, (2,5), (3,4), (3,5), (4,5)$

Here, order does not matter because we select card simultaneously.

Total number of ways to select two cards simultaneously $=10$

Possible event to get both even numbered cards $=1$

Therefore, required probability $=\cfrac{1}{10}$

Answer (score 1):

The possible outcomes for the two cards should be any combination of numbers in 1 to numbers in 5, which is 5*4/2 = 10 outcomes total. Of these only 2 and 4 are even, so the probability of even is 1/10.

Comment: Thanks was thinking same thing just needed clarification